# Why are avocados so expensive?

Tags: avocados

Avocados are in my opinion one the most loved fruit in the world. I live in South Africa, for a ready ripe avocado you would easily pay between R25 (1.61 usd) and R40 (2.58 usd). For a South African this is ridiculously expensive. We are experiencing one of the worst droughts in our county’s history. But even before the drought they we in the price range they are in now.

We probably import most of our avocados seeing that the drought did not shoot up the price with that much.  Which led me thinking what does affect the price of an avocado? Why are they so expensive?

Comment: Well that price is in the same rough range in my region of the USA. As far as the drought is concerned, avacado trees drink a LOT of water. More than many other crops. If you are experiencing true draught, then you likely are inporting avacados which makes them expensive.

Comment: @Escoce If you have an answer, please post it below. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supply and demand.

Supplies of avocados are declining due to droughts and unusual weather patterns. Not only drought can reduce crops, but unusual cool weather patterns can as well. Avocados dislike temperatures lower than 10°C and have absolutely no frost tolerance.

Demand for avocados is going steadily upward as more people enjoy cuisines in which they are popular, such as Mexican and many South American dishes. Avocado oil is becoming more in demand as people consume it for its healthy omegas, and cooks use it due to its high smoke-point.

Declining supply + rising demand = high prices.